# Is 说 in 听说 a resultative compliment?

Tags: grammar

My assignment is:

### Fill in the blanks with the proper resultative complements.

我听__ 老师走路的声音，大家快进教室。
(I heard that the teacher is walking, …)

Can the answer be 说, or is that not a resultative compliment, in which case it can only be 过 or 到？

Comment: FWIW, the sentence feels more natural with 了. E. g.  我听到/见老师走路的声音了，大家快进教室。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "到".

if you use "說" , its meaning will become "It`s said that.. "

Answer (score 2):

'到' is the correct resultative complement for indicating the verb '听' is successfully carried out (听 = to hear; **听到** = have heard/ successfully hear)

听 and 说 in  "听说" are both verbs.

[听说] = [听 (indefinite object. *e.g. 別人; 有人; 某人*) 说] with the indefinite object omitted

*You can use 听到 for any sound, but you can only use 听说 for human speech*

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you! I hadn't thought about an indefinit object being omitted!

Answer (score 2):

[**听说**](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%90%AC%E8%AF%B4) means "heard", but more in the sense of "heard through the grapevine".  E.g.

> 我**听说**你和女朋友分手了。
> I **heard** you and your girlfriend broke up.

In both English and Chinese, it doesn't imply you're literally hearing anything (e.g. you could have read it on Facebook).  This is not the appropriate "heard" to describe the sound made when the teacher walks.

(*Side note*: the translation "I heard that the teacher is walking" is imprecise.  This translation suggests you indirectly became aware of the fact that the teacher is walking, e.g., someone told you that the teacher is walking.)

The 过 in **听过** is the "experiential" aspect 过:

> > Subj. + Verb + 过 + Obj.
>
> What this expresses is that the verb *has been* done at least once before, without specifying a particular time. 过 (guo) is used to talk about whether something has *ever* happened - whether it *has been experienced*.
> <sub>[Expressing experiences with "guo"](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_experiences_with_%22guo%22), Chinese Grammar Wiki</sub>

It is not appropriate to use 听过 to describe something you're hearing right now (such as the teachers sound when walking).  It's more suitable to describe something you've heard a small number of times in your life.  E.g.

> 我**听过**这首歌。
> I've **heard** this song.

The only correct choice among those suggested is [**听到**](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%90%AC%E5%88%B0) (although [**听见**](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%90%AC%E8%A7%81) also works): see [Result complements "-dao" and "-jian"](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Result_complements_%22-dao%22_and_%22-jian%22).  Unlike the above, these are results complements:

> In Chinese, verbs tend to be of the 'look' and 'listen' variety - the result isn't included like it is in 'see' and 'hear'. So if you want to indicate the result, you have to use a result complement. ...
>
> - 听 means 'to listen' but doesn't include 'to hear'.
>
> <sub>[Result complement](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Result_complement), Chinese Grammar Wiki</sub>

So we have:

> 我**听到**老师走路的声音，大家快进教室。
> I **hear** the sound of the teacher walking, [and] everyone quickly enters the classroom.

(The tense is not clear from the Chinese sentence; it depends on context.)